# can I set constraints directly to superview in a custom view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, autolayout

A pretty simple question I reckon:

one `UIViewController`

one custom `UIView`

The controller only does:

```
-(void)loadView{
   [super loadView];
   self.sideMenu = [[sideMenuView alloc]init];
   [self.view addSubview:self.sideMenu];
}
```

and in the `UIView` I would like to do something like:

```
      self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:100];
[self.superview addConstraint:constraint];
```

So that when I create the UIView in the controller its constraints is already set in relation to the controller.

I have tried and nothing crashes but the `UIView` gets realy weird x and y coords

Maby I need to update the constraints? Or maby this isnt at all possible?

Comment: If you use the visual format language, the pipe (`|`) character represents the superview. So `@"|-100-[self]"` would work for the constraint you showed, assuming you pass `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self)` as the `views` to `-constraintsWithVisualFormat:...`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what ui behavior you are exactly looking for since it appears that you are trying to tie the leading space of your view to the leading space of it's superview. Being the leading space, the space on the left of the view, could it be that you are looking for the more common "stick my left side 100 pixels from my parents left border"? Anyway, in either case, I would connect an outlet from the controller to the custom view (i.e. myCustomView below) and then build the constraint in the UIViewController and not the UIView by overriding:

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myCustomView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:myCustomView.superview
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                 multiplier:1
                                                                   constant:100];
    [myCustomView addConstraint:constraint];
}
```

Apple has an interesting page with a table showing the various runtime entry points for autolayout at this address:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/runtime.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH6-SW1

You might consider adding other constraints as well. Auto layout has the the tendency to exploit any freedom you leave unchecked in the worst possible way ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I just added this one constraint to give a hint at what I was aiming at.

My thought with the question was to have like a library where I could just init views and they would set themselves.

I realy doubted I could do this but a question to confirm it is always nice :)

Comment: Views CAN setup themselves. Override `updateConstraints` in your custom view, call super and add your constraints there.

Comment: Just to expand a little further. A view can setup it's own constraints by overriding `updateConstraints` but during that call it should not reference it's superview. The allowed constraints must reside in it's subtree.

Comment: I think I got this now.
So I create a method in my customclass with all constraints where I reference customclass to superview.
And insted of calling the method within the custom class itself i call it from the superclass in `- (void)updateViewConstraints`
and voila, it works

Tnx for the help and hints

Answer (score 1):

So leading edge is not enough. 
You need enough constraints to satisfy vertical and horizontal layout.

In one direction you need at least

one edge & width (or hight)
Or
Two edges ( implicit width or height )
Or
A horizontal (or vertical) center based constraint and an explicit width ( or height respectively)

The thing about width and height is that they can also be determined by intrinsic content size.

Add constraints after adding the view to the superview.

Comment: Thanks. I just added this one constraint to give a hint at what I was aiming at.

My thought with the question was to have like a library where I could just init views and they would set themselves.

I realy doubted I could do this but a question to confirm it is always nice :)

Comment: Yes a view can have reference to its own constraints and can even add them itself once it knows it has a superview or knows it has moved to a new superview. This is a useful design but isn't always possible

Comment: any example how I can reference the superview it has been added to?

Comment: self.superview will work. It will be nil if there is no superview.

Comment: That is to say all views have the method superview

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but PureLayout is pretty handy https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout